# How to import from python package huawei-modem-api-client?

Tags: python, import

Newbie question ::
I have installed huawei-modem-api-client as shown below.

How do I import 'huaweisms'?

This is my first try:

```
    import huawei-modem-api-client
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Second try:

```
    import huaweisms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huaweisms'
```

or

```
    import huaweisms.api.user
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huaweisms'
```

I tried `import requests` which is in the same directory as huawei-
modem-api-client and that did not generate any error

```
C:\Users\Lars>python -m pip show huawei-modem-api-client
Name: huawei-modem-api-client
Version: 1.1.2
Summary: huaweisms is a python api client for Huawei Modems.
Home-page: https://github.com/pablo/huawei-modem-python-api-client
Author: Pablo Santa Cruz, Mkhanyisi Madlavana
Author-email: xxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xx, xxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\lars\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages
Requires: certifi, chardet, idna, requests, six, typing, urllib3
Required-by:
```

Comment: Yes, I get a syntax error on the - character. Added compiler output to orignal question.

Comment: Hyphens in module names are not allowed in python which is why you're getting a syntax error. Try importing `huaweisms` instead

Comment: @tyagdit, tried that, copied result to original question.

Comment: Are you using the same virtual environment?

Comment: @mxp-xc don't know what a virtual environment is. I am using VSCode with the Python extension if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The package description lists the github address.

There, it shows [Example usage](https://github.com/pablo/huawei-modem-python-api-client#example):

```
import huaweisms.api.user
import huaweisms.api.wlan
import huaweisms.api.sms
```

Comment: I started with the Example code verbatim which gave me     import huaweisms.api.user
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huaweisms'

Comment: Sorry about being a newbie, when I saw your answer I realised I should have included more info in my question.

Comment: Yes, I did a pip install. The path is "C:\Users\Lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\huaweisms\api\user.py" Not sure what my install folder is?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Somehow, where pip installed to, must not be where your python is looking for modules. See [Where does Python look for modules?](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html). Or on Windows, `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Seems like sys.path is different between cmd python and vscode pyton. I will have to investigate.